# Only one usage of each socket address address (python selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a few Python selenium scripts running on a computer, these scripts open, close, and create chromedriver object instances regularly.
After some time of doing this, I get an error "Only one usage of each socket address" on all scripts except for one, the one that doesn't get the error is throwing timeout exceptions.

I'm trying to catch the error but it still is thrown and not caught.

How do I fix the main issue?
Is there too many object instances?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but it was happening with Firefox. On more investigation I found that there were two different Firefox installations on my comp: x86 and x64. I uninstalled the x86 version and the error got resolved.

Check if you've got two different instances of chrome installed on your pc. If yes, then remove one of them.